# How can I delete Time Machine backups, moved into trash?

Tags: finder, backup, time-machine, filesystem, trash

I was going to delete the Time Machine backups. I made a mistake and instead of deleting them using Time Machine, I just moved the **Backups.backupdb** folder to the trash. Now, if I try to empty the trash, Finder attempts to count the number of files that will be deleted, and this process is incredibly time-consuming, because the Finder tries to count each file in each backup. The same thing happens if I try to move the **Backups.backupdb** folder from the trash back on my hard drive where it was before.

What can I do in this situation? How can I delete the backups?

Comment: Do you use the (probably) external drive exclusively for Time Machine backups? If so, is your Mac the only machine backed up or do you use the external drive to also backup other Macs?

Comment: @klanomath Thank you, I used an external drive for backups but I also keep a lot of files on this drive. My Mac is the only machine that was backed up.

Comment: So just formatting/erasing it is **no** option!

Comment: @klanomath Do you mean formatting the Mac or the external drive?..

Comment: I meant the external drive - but I already wrote an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To remove or move the Backups.backupdb folder open Terminal.app.

- Enter `cd /Volumes/<Name_of_BackupDrive>/.Trashes` to change the working directory. `<Name_of_BackupDrive>` has to be the volume name of your TM backup volume.
- Enter `sudo ls -laO` to show all folders. Usually you should see only one folder with  the name *501* now:

  ```
  d-wx-wx-wt@ 3 root      wheel  hidden 102 Jun 25 20:52 .
  drwxrwxr-x  9 root      admin  -      374 Jun 26 01:21 ..
  drwx------@ 2 user      staff  hidden  68 Jun 26 01:21 501
  ```
- Enter `sudo su` to get super user rights.
- Enter `cd 501` (Replace 501 with whatever the name of the directory is) to change the working directory and list the content of the folder *501* with `ls -laO`. Now you should see the folder *Backups.backupdb*:

  ```
  drwx------@ 3 user      staff  hidden 102 Jun 26 01:21 .
  d-wx-wx-wt@ 3 root      wheel  hidden 102 Jun 25 20:52 ..
  drwxr-xr-x  2 user      admin  -       68 Jun 26 01:19 Backups.backupdb
  ```
- Now you may either move the folder back to the root of the backup drive with:

  ```
  mv Backups.backupdb /Volumes/<Name_of_BackupDrive>/
  ```

  or remove the folder with

  ```
  rm -dR Backups.backupdb
  ```

  If you are asked to override something (e.g. `override rw-r--r--  root/wheel uchg for Backups.backupdb/.RecoverySets/0/com.apple.recovery.boot/boot.efi?`) enter `yes` and hit the return button. You may also add the `-f` option to skip confirmations.

---

To delete a 30 GB backup in a virtual machine it took about 3 minutes. So depending on the size of Backups.backupdb some patience is needed.

Comment: It worked fine, it took like 1 hour to delete 280 gb.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to delete the trash with help of the free program Onyx: http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html You open the program and gå to "clean", then to "Trash" and then click on "delete". The program will delete the content in the Trash for all connected volumes (for example Time Machine).

Comment: How does it do this differently from Finder?

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, I was looking how to delete thise files, ONYXmakes the magic in ONE GO.

Answer (score 0):

First off, thank you so much for the help! I just wanted to include a few steps that were different for my setup- just in case it can help someone else.

I was using a WD external backup drive:

1. Go to the root folder, where you can get to the Volumes directory:

   - cd ../..
2. Change to the volumes directory:

   - cd Volumes/My\ Passport
3. View all folders:

   - sudo ls -laO
4. Get super user rights:

   - sudo su
     5 Look for the .Trashes directory and change into it.
   - Each director is listed at the end of each line.
   - cd .Trashes
5. List the contents of the .Trashes directory:

   - ls -laO
6. Look for a 501 folder and remove it:

   - rm -dR 501

Comment: On behalf of an anonymous user:
"open teminal type sudo chmod -R 777 "drag and drop one folder or file from trash bin" press enter type in password if asked. it takes about 3 min to execute the command. again type sudo rm -R " drag and drop the same file." press enter enter password if asked.

takes time 3 mins approx.

this should work as i tried many options only this worked for me. if successful repeat the commands by dragging and dropping all the files that are to be deleted. both steps are required."